# Error in code? Calculating the number of operations to make a palindrome from the user input string

Tags: palindrome

Problem Statement

James found a love letter his friend Harry has written for his girlfriend. James is a prankster, so he decides to meddle with the letter. He changes all the words in the letter into palindromes.

To do this, he follows two rules:

He can reduce the value of a letter, e.g. he can change d to c, but he cannot change c to d.
In order to form a palindrome, if he has to repeatedly reduce the value of a letter, he can do it until the letter becomes a. Once a letter has been changed to a, it can no longer be changed.
Each reduction in the value of any letter is counted as a single operation. Find the minimum number of operations required to convert a given string into a palindrome.

Input Format

The first line contains an integer T, i.e., the number of test cases. 
The next T lines will contain a string each. The strings do not contain any spaces.

Constraints 
1≤T≤10 
1≤ length of string ≤104 
All characters are lower case English letters.

Output Format

A single line containing the number of minimum operations corresponding to each test case.

MY CODE-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void funct(char array[],int x){
    x--;
    int i;
    unsigned j;
    int p;
    unsigned z=0;
    if(x%2==0){
        p=x/2;
        for(i=0;i<=p;i++){
            j=(int)array[i]-(int)array[x-i];
            printf("j is %d\n",j);
            z=z+j;
        }  
    }
    else if(x%2!=0){
        p=(x/2)-1;
        for(i=0;i<=p;i++){
            j=(int)array[i]-(int)array[x-i];
            printf("j is %d\n",j);
            z=z+j;
        }
   }
    printf("%u\n",z);
}
int main() {
    int i,t,j,output;
    char input[10000];
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(i=1;i<=t;i++){
        fgets(input,10000,stdin);
        int x=strlen(input);
        funct(input,x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The logic doesn't give me the right output.But I can't figure out why.
Can someone help me?